# Как настроить линтер для html в vscode?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, eslint

Возникла необходимость в редактировании html в vscode. Проблема в том, что когда вставляю текст и хочу довести его до ума код отформатирован чёрте как. Для JavaScript есть отличный инструмент для приведения кода к единому стилю - eslint.
Для html чего то подобного не нашёл. В идеале хотелось бы, чтобы при нажатии ctrl+k ctrl+f код выглядел бы удобочитаемым. Какие есть плагины для этого и как их настраивать?

Comment: Попробуй такую комбинация если я тебя правильно понял :?
ctrl + alt +l ?????

Comment: Vscode не idea. Тут так просто выравнивание не работает.

Answer (score 0):

Раньше использовал Beautify, но есть одно маленькое но :) В связке с eslint нужно/можно/модномолодежно использовать prettier что бы форматировать код в соответствии с заданными правилами в eslint по штатному сочетанию кнопок. Проблема в том что prettier конфликтует с beautify, потому полностью перешел на связку eslint + prettier и вам советую. https://prettier.io/ UPD: на сайте заметил ссылку на https://github.com/Unibeautify/vscode , возможно это то что вы ищите:)

Answer (score 0):

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/html#_formatting

В документации все есть. Используй команду format document